# Sudo times out during long running script

Tags: sudo

I have a long running script which issues several `sudo` prefaced commands.  The execution time of the script is variable, and occasionally `sudo` times out while the script is running, meaning that I need to re-enter the password.

How can I run this script without needing to check the program and make sure it's still going?

Answer (score 9):

If the script itself is run as `sudo`, it will not time out until the script has finished running.  To ensure that `sudo` is used to run the script, I inserted the following lines near the top of my script:

```sh
if [ `whoami` != 'root' ];
then
    echo "This program needs to be run using 'sudo'"
    exit
fi
```

This ensures that the script has been started with `sudo`, and does not make any attempt to store passwords...

Comment: This can be a problem if only parts of the script need to be run with sudo and the rest should not be (for example, creating files with root ownership in a user folder  can be problematic).

Comment: @JAB I can see how that would be an issue - I should look about and see if there's a way around that.

Comment: @jab You can de-escalate using `su "$(logname)"`, e.g. `su "$(logname)" -c 'echo $USER'`

Comment: @wjandrea So presumably I could `su  "$(logname)" -c 'some command that does stuff'` and not disturb the permissions that my script has?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I haven't actually used it in practice, sorry, I just know the method.

Comment: @wjandrea Just tested it in my small test script - it does work the way the I had supposed!

Comment: This concept can be used to make scripts with GUI work in Wayland (for example by calling `zenity` with the user ID that owns the desktop).

Comment: Alternatively, `sudo` sets the `SUDO_USER`, `SUDO_UID`, and `SUDO_GID` environment variables which allows you to use: `sudo -u "#${SUDO_UID:-0}" -g "#${SUDO_GID:-0}" -- COMMAND [ARGS...]`